# SSIS package failed due to incompatible data types

Tags: ssis

In ssis after data conversion in advanced editor to convert data and matched lookup columns but its showing error incompatible data types

Comment: We need more information to reproduce your situation. Please review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center to improve your question and get an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is provably your source and destination column type does not match.